# How to write to UNIX terminal through system calls?

Tags: c, unix

I have been working on 'C' for quite sometime.

I would like to say 'Hello ' to my team mates when they open the terminal and logon for the first time of the day

I found this post a useful one

[Not able to read data from other terminal using read() system call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202835/not-able-to-read-data-from-other-terminal-using-read-system-call][1])

How can I write to **others terminal** (because, in pts/n - n will differ from person to person) and say the welcome message ?

Comment: Why do you want to read from the terminal? You only need to write to it in order to display a message. (Which, by the way, your coworkers will likely only find annoying.)

Comment: @Ross I edited the question and that was just a scenario created by me to find out the way to write to any terminal

Comment: Are you asking how to write to a terminal or how to find out which terminal to write to?

Comment: @Ross I want to write to the terminal to selected users of a group for sharing some important info and I need both ie finding out the terminal and writing to it

Comment: You're going to need to think about how you'll establish who was on the system the last time you looked, who is on the system now, and which of those need a greeting.  Depending on how you do that (`who`?), you may have the terminal information on hand.  Don't forget that your colleagues may decide they don't like this treatment and they may block you by making their terminal unwritable by you.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  `man 1 write`

Answer (score 0):

This possibly is the simplest of programs you can get with out much validations and error handling etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if ( argc != 3 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage : msend \"terminal\" \"message\" ");
        exit(1);
    }

    char filePath[256] = {0,};

    if ( strncmp( argv[1], "/dev/pts", strlen("/dev/pts") ) )  {
        sprintf( filePath, "/dev/%s" , argv[1] );   
    } else {
        sprintf( filePath, "%s", argv[1] );
    }

    int fd = open( filePath , O_RDWR , O_APPEND);

    write( fd, argv[2], strlen(argv[2]) );

    return 0;
}
```

Try building on top of this.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try my best